# C++ winapi LONG to std double

Tags: c++, winapi, double, long-integer

I'm messing with some stuff in the `winapi` and I'm trying to get the cursor position with `GetCursorPos(POINT)` and store the `x` and `y` in a list. The list I have is:

```
double cursor[2];
```

So you might already see what I need. `POINT's` `x` and `y` values are `winapi LONGS`. I can cast em to an `std long` easy just with

```
POINT cPos;
(long) cPos.x;
```

but I can't cast it to a double. I need it to be in double format because of the math that I'm going to apply to it so that everything works alright.

Basically what I get when casting is it just gives me 0

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: What happens when you try to cast it to a double?

Comment: `cursor[0] = (double)cPos.x;` - error in compilation or does not work? Have you seen the values after GetCursorPos()?

Comment: "I can't cast it to a double" - why not? What goes wrong?

Comment: BTW, cPos.x is already LONG type - nothing to cast in your example.

Comment: It just gives me 0. without the cast it prints out something like 364 but when I do cast its always 0

Comment: `(double) pt.x` gives you 0? What's the full expression? That sounds like a weird bug somewhere (be it in your code or in the compiler...) Or are you trying to do something like `(double) (1 / pt.x)` which definitely will not work because that's integer division?

Comment: I really don't know what it was. Its working fine now I think it was just something on my end. No I make sure to give numbers a decimal point in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to cast from `LONG` to `double`. You can simply write:

```
cursor[0] = cPos.x;
cursor[1] = cPos.y;
```

Comment: Ok this actually did work. That's a little weird. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `(long) cPos.x` is fine too, albeit needless. I guess we could explain the weirdness if we saw the original code. That said, the right way to write this is as per my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to do intermediate cast. I.e. use (double)cPos.x and (double)cPos.y in your math expression without this `cursor[2]` array.

Comment: When I do it just gives me 0.

Comment: Have you debugged the integer value of cPos.x and what was? Maybe other operand in expression is the reason for 0 result.

Comment: I'm literally just printing out the value of cPos.x. without the cast it prints 364. with it, it prints 0

Comment: Ok. Paste here the math expression which uses cPos.x. Sometimes it is better to use integer multiply and then divide instead of casting to double.

Comment: The math is pretty long and goes through functions so I wouldn't really be able to post it here

Comment: @DavidLudwig How are you printing out the value?

Comment: Try with `printf( "%lf\n", (double)cPos.x );`.